# Where I can find passport keys in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I generated a keys using the Laravel command `php artisan passport:keys` but I don't know where I can find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When reading [the source code](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/3.0/src/Console/KeysCommand.php) I find it gets its path [from `$keyPath`](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/3.0/src/Passport.php). Which can be set with `loadKeysFrom($path)`. or uses the default location from [`storage_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-storage-path). So this is `storage` by default.

Answer (score 13):

The default path is **storage** folder.

There are two files with the following names:

```
oauth-private.key

oauth-public.key
```

Laravel version: 5.8

Answer (score 1):

You can find the keys generated by the command

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

in the storage folder. If your project name is laravel_project the

```
laravel_project/storage/ oauth-private.key and oauth-public.key
```

[image]