# Laravel Passport : How to query 'passport keys'？

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport

After running `php artisan passport:keys`,I closed the command line window,I forgot the `client_id` and `client_secret`, how to show them?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304627/where-i-can-find-passport-keys-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

The clients are stored in a database table called `oauth_clients` so one way would be to simply use a query:

```
DB::table('oauth_clients')->pluck('secret', 'id');
```

Alternatively, if you have a database GUI (e.g. Sequel Pro, phpMyAdmin, etc.) you could just use that to look in the table.